# Guess custom form type when embedding custom classes

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

Two simple classes form my app model: `Money` and `Product`.

As `Money` app form being reusable, I've decided to create `MoneyType` extending `AbstractType`.

```php
// App\Entity\Product

/**
* @ORM\Embedded(class="Money\Money")
*/
private $price;
```

```php
// App\Form\ProductType

$builder->add('price', MoneyType::class)
```

```php
// App\Form\Type\MoneyType

class MoneyType extends AbstractType
{
    private $transformer;

    public function __construct(MoneyToArrayTransformer $transformer)
    {
        $this->transformer = $transformer;
    }

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('amount', NumberType::class, [
                'html5' => true,
                'constraints' => [
                    new NotBlank(),
                    new PositiveOrZero(),
                ],
                'attr' => [
                    'min' => '0',
                    'step' => '0.01',
                ],
            ])
            ->add('currency', ChoiceType::class, [
                'choices' => $this->getCurrenciesChoices(),
                'constraints' => [
                    new NotBlank(),
                ],
            ]);

        $builder->addModelTransformer($this->transformer);
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        parent::configureOptions($resolver);

        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => null
        ]);
    }

    ...
}
```

Is it possible to guess the field type without specifying it explicitly for obtaining the following code?

```php
// App\Form\ProductType

$builder->add('price')
```

Any help is welcome. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Sorry but you want to build your "prince" field as a `MoneyType` field without write it in your `$builder` ? I think it's possible but it's will be much more complicated than just writing it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement a [custom `TypeGuesser`](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/type_guesser.html#guessing-the-type) that reads the doctrine [metadata](https://www.doctrine-project.org/api/orm/2.5/Doctrine/ORM/Mapping/ClassMetadataInfo.html) and checks if the field is an embeddable of the desired type. This is a basic implementation

```
namespace App\Form\TypeGuesser;

use App\Form\Type\MoneyType;

use Symfony\Component\Form\Guess\Guess;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Guess\TypeGuess;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormTypeGuesserInterface;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;

class MoneyTypeGuesser implements FormTypeGuesserInterface
{
    private $em;

    public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $em)
    {
        $this->em = $em;    
    }

    public function guessType($class, $property) 
    {
        if (!$metadata = $this->em->getClassMetadata($class)) {
            return null;
        }

        if (
            isset($metadata->embeddedClasses[$property]) && 
            'Money\Money' == $metadata->embeddedClasses[$property]['class']
        ) {
            return new TypeGuess(MoneyType::class, [], Guess::HIGH_CONFIDENCE);
        }
    }

    // Other interface functions ommited for brevity, you can return null
}
```

You can see all the interface methods that you need to implement [here](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/4.3/src/Symfony/Component/Form/FormTypeGuesserInterface.php).

Answer (score 0):

The Form TypeGuesser is mostly based on the annotation `@var Money\Money` and you should be able to build your down guesser for your own types, see https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/type_guesser.html

Also take a look at https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/4.3/src/Symfony/Bridge/Doctrine/Form/DoctrineOrmTypeGuesser.php on how to guess the type by doctrine orm specific types.

You could derive your own app specific guesser with those two examples.